# C# Active Directory authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have a heavy client side webapp in AngularJS. I'm using a C# controller to do Active Directory authentication, here is this code.

```
public UserModel Get()
{
        UserModel currentUser = new UserModel();
        currentUser.name = User.Identity.Name;
      //  currentUser.auth = contactFromAD(User.Identity.Name);
        currentUser.auth = true;
        return currentUser;
}
```

So what its doing is checking what AD account you are logged into, then performing some logic to check if you are authenticated to access the site.

However how can I get this to work outside of localhost. When the code is running server, how can I get `User.Identity.Name` to return the identity of the person currently using the app.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand AngularJS angle. If I had a regular WCF service I would use WindowsIdentity from ServiceSecurityContext.Current.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx

```
ServiceSecurityContext securityContext = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;

if (securityContext == null)
     throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve Service Security Context");

WindowsIdentity identity = securityContext.WindowsIdentity;
currentUser.name = identity.Name
```